# join strings without NA

Tags: r, stringr

I want to summarise strings without na.

It is working with str_c like in the following example

**Code**

```
df <- tibble(x = c("ISSUE-1", "ISSUE-2", "ISSUE-3", "ISSUE-4"), ID = c("ID-1", "ID-1", "ID-2", "ID-2")) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(IDissue = str_c(x, collapse = "; "))
```

**Output**

```
ID          issueID
ID-1    ISSUE-1; ISSUE-2
ID-2    ISSUE-3; ISSUE-4
```

But when there is a NA in the column str_c converts the complete output to NA as mentioned in the documentation:
https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_c.html

> Like most other R functions, missing values are "infectious": whenever a missing value is combined with another string the result will always be missing. Use str_replace_na() to convert NA to "NA"
> **Code**

```
df <- tibble(x = c("ISSUE-1", "ISSUE-2", "ISSUE-3", NA), ID = c("ID-1", "ID-1", "ID-2", "ID-2")) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(IDissue = str_c(x, collapse = "; "))
```

**Output**

```
ID    IDissue
ID-1    ISSUE-1; ISSUE-2
ID-2    NA
```

Is there a way to get as Output?

```
ID    IDissue
ID-1    ISSUE-1; ISSUE-2
ID-2    ISSUE-3
```

Comment: Use `na.omit` to remove `NA` values. `%>% summarise(IDissue = str_c(na.omit(x), collapse = "; "))`

Comment: Thanks, this is working perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Easier would be to add a `filter` before the `group_by`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
tibble(x = c("ISSUE-1", "ISSUE-2", "ISSUE-3", NA), 
     ID = c("ID-1", "ID-1", "ID-2", "ID-2")) %>%  
  filter(!is.na(x)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(IDissue = str_c(x, collapse = "; "))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use paste or str_c with x[!is.na(x)] instead of x; it works.

```
library(dplyr)    
df <- tibble(x = c("ISSUE-1", "ISSUE-2", "ISSUE-3", NA), ID = c("ID-1", "ID-1", "ID- 
          2", "ID-2")) %>%
          group_by(ID) %>%
          summarise(IDissue = paste(x[!is.na(x)], collapse = "; "))
df
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option via using `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(.~ID,df,function(x) paste0(na.omit(x),collapse = "; "))
    ID                x
1 ID-1 ISSUE-1; ISSUE-2
2 ID-2          ISSUE-3
```